# Https запросы через Volley Android

Tags: java, android, https

Андроид приложение выдает ошибку на POST и GET запросы с таким текстом:

> com.android.volley.NoConnectionError:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

Гугл подсказывает, что ошибка связана с тем, что на сервере используется SSL сертификат не авторизированного CA (Certificate authority / поставщика сертификата). Мы использовали сначала этот:

https://ssl.com.ua/

потом этот:

https://www.gogetssl.com/

После смены этих двух сертификатов проблема осталась.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673568/does-android-volley-support-ssl/32674422) в комментариях говориться, что Volley умеет обрабатывать https запросы - достаточно просто изменить http на https в своем url и все будет работать как нужно без какого либо дополнительного кода.

На сколько я понял из официальной документацией Android, если использовать сертификат хорошо известного поставщика сертификатов, то ошибок быть не должно.

> The host platform generally contains a list of well known CAs that it
>   trusts. As of Android 4.2 (Jelly Bean), Android currently contains
>   over 100 CAs that are updated in each release.

**В связи с этим вопросы:**

Сертификат какого поставщика вам приходилось использовать, чтобы Volley без проблем обрабатывал https запросы (не хочется просто так заплатить за новый сертифика)?

Может быть я неверно использую метод POST. Вот мой код:

```
private void userRegistration(){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url + REG, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Все прошло хорошо!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected java.util.Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            java.util.Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(EMAIL, userEmail);
            params.put(PASSWORD, userPass);
            return params;
        }
    };
    final RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**Вот информация, которую я перечитал вдоль и в поперек:**

- [Официальный туториал](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#UnknownCa) от гугла, который подсказывает как решить ошибку
- [Соответствующая тема](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673568/does-android-volley-support-ssl/32674422) на Stackoverflow, которая помогла решить ошибку, но данное решение не похоже на best practice.
- [Это решение](http://ogrelab.ikratko.com/using-android-volley-with-self-signed-certificate/) не помогло.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вы отправляете https запросы в Android через Volley и не попадаете на эту ошибку? И сертификат какого поставщика используете?

Comment: совет - volley deprecated. переходите на ретрофит

Comment: @Sviat Volkov серьезно? А где написано на офф сайте, что использовать Volley не рекомендуется? В документации ни единого слова не сказано о volley deprecated. Можно ссылку на какой-то источник?